# maven condition based on os family

Tags: maven, parameters, operating-system

I am trying to do the following:

```xml
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-jre</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jre</artifactId>
                                <version>${jdk.version}-${os.family}-x64</version>
                                <type>zip</type>
                            </artifactItem>                             
                        </artifactItems>
                        <outputDirectory>${target-deployer.cnc.dir}/java/${os.family}/x86_64/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

I want to copy dependency based on the os - windows or linux in my case.
But I cant find the correct parameter

Comment: Your pom snippet looks incomplete.  Are you using a maven plugin - like http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/index.html - to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to do this.

e.g.

```
<profile>
    <id>platform-windows</id>
    <activation>
        <os>
            <family>windows</family>
        </os>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

In your case, you might just want to specify os/family in the profile's activation element.

Answer (score 3):

The Sonatype book, ["Maven: The Complete Reference"](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html#resource-filtering-sect-system-properties) section 9.2 deals with maven properties and lists the following properties that are pertinent to your question:

```
java.version
os.name
```

The java.version property seems usable and in my testing returned "1.6.0_27". However, the os.name property is not exactly an "os family" as you requested. In my case os.name returns "Windows Vista", which I imagine is not what you are hoping for. I don't know of a property to get the os family as you desire it so I recommend using maven profiles as prunge mentioned to handle configuring your plugins with the desired os.