# Is there a way to alter maven dependency tree via custom maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a project. This project could have different dependencies based on calculation. The idea is to write custom maven plugin that will calculate this dependencies and will alter dependencies tree by adding own dependencies. 
The question is: how actually change dependency tree.

All I found yet is injecting "DependencyTreeBuilder" for getting dependencies tree, but it is not possible to change the tree.

Comment: What do you mean by `could have different dependencies based on calculation` ..Can you give a more detailed example ?

Comment: if user's OS is "Windows" then I will include one library, otherwise another, and if it is linux, I will perform some other checkings for already available runtime libraries and theirs versions - this is actually my case

Comment: Maybe there can be an easier way, did you take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963713/maven-condition-based-on-os-family

Comment: I know about that possibility, but still I need to perform operation  via plugin, as far as plugin will be configurable itself, and configuration will affect selection of depencencies, so it is not only os-based.

Comment: I understand, I am also interested in your question by licensing point, I hope you will get an answer, if not I just can imagine lot of coding and nested exceptions