# Java: set pom.xml property

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have Java `Meven` project and inside my `pom.xml` i have this `property`:

```
<properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <JAVA_1_8_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
         <fork>true</fork>
         <executable>${JAVA_1_8_HOME}</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So i case i am running my project from `Windows` i just type `mvn test`

In case i am with `MACOS/Linux` this path doesn't exist and i wonder what solutions can be found to fix this issue.

**UPDATE**

As suggestion here i add this profile:

```
<profile>
            <id>platform-windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>mac</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <executable>/usr/bin/javac</executable>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Now how my code will now to run this particular id ?

Comment: The solution is using profiles:https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this configuration in two ways:

---

#### 1) Explicit Profile

Open Maven `pom.xml` file available in your project directory:

```
<properties>
    <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    <JAVA_1_8_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\javac.exe</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
    <JAVA_1_8_HOME_LINUX>/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181/</JAVA_1_8_HOME_LINUX>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <!-- Windows Profile-->
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-8-windows</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
       <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>${JAVA_1_8_HOME}</executable>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

   <!-- Mac/Linux Profile-->
    <profile>
        <id>jdk-8-linux</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <executable>${JAVA_1_8_HOME_LINUX}</executable>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
   </profile>
   
</profiles>
```

- Default active profile was defined as: jdk-8-windows
- If the main profile is Mac/Linux, use: `<activeProfile>jdk-8linux</activeProfile>`
- To execute your Mac/Linux profile use: `mvn test -P jdk-8-linux`

---

#### 2) Profile Activation via Maven Settings

Open Maven `settings.xml` file available in `%USER_HOME%/.m2` directory where `%USER_HOME%` represents the user home directory. If `settings.xml` file is not there, then create a new one.

```
<settings>
  [...]
  <profiles>
    [...]

    <!-- Windows Profile-->
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-8-windows</id>
        <properties>
          <JAVA_1_8_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\j2sdk1.4.2_09</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <!-- Mac/Linux Profile-->
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-8-linux</id>
        <properties>
          <JAVA_1_8_HOME_LINUX>/usr/bin/javac</JAVA_1_8_HOME_LINUX>
        </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
  [...]
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>windows</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

- Default active profile was defined as: jdk-8-windows
- If the main profile is Mac/Linux, use: `<activeProfile>linux</activeProfile>`
- To execute your Mac/Linux profile use: `mvn test -P jdk-8-linux`

---

#### Reference:

- [Maven - Build Profiles](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_build_profiles.htm)
- [Compiling Sources Using A Different JDK](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)

Comment: Where i need to define this activeProfile ?

Comment: I cannot find where place where this activeProfiles should locate

Comment: @dannykob I made some changes in the answer, please check if it helped...

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the property as a command line argument when running the `mvn` command, for example:

`mvn test"-DJAVA_1_8_HOME=<OS specific path>"`

For another solutions, take a look at [maven condition based on os family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963713/maven-condition-based-on-os-family)

**For profiles:**

```
<project>
    <profiles>
         <profile>
             <properties>
                 // Define profile specific properties here
             </properties>
         </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

After defining the profile specific properties, use them as you would use any other property.

Comment: Where i need to put this profile tag exactly in the pom file ? ?

Comment: Please see my edit, after add this windows profile my code will automatically know that it need to take that javac path ?

Comment: You have to move the property definitions under profiles, the rest of your pom.xml should stay the same.

Comment: But as you can see i defined this profile tag twice, where i need to move it ?

Comment: Under <project> you define <profiles> and under <profiles> you add the <profile> tags.

Comment: I dont need this properties cause i moved this javac path inside each profile (windows and os), please see my edit, this is looks ok now ?

Comment: It might work, but there's a lot of duplication for a single different line.

Comment: What do you mean single different line ?

Comment: You've duplicated the build tag within each profile just to set up a different Java8 location. You could specify only the java 8 location in the profile (as a property) and move the plugin declaration outside of <profiles> and reference the profile specific Java8 property.